# Why am I getting a TypeError "'float' object is not iterable" using `sum`?

Tags: python, csv

I am trying to run calculations between values in a .csv file. However, when I try to execute the code, it gives an error that the while loop is not iterable. My code is:

```
import csv
import math
counter_chime = 1
chime_cra = 0
chime_cdec = 0
fermi_cra = 0
fermi_cdec = 0
grbfrb_overlap = []
frbcode = ""
grbcode = ""
dis = 0
counter_fermi = 0

class adata():
    def __init__(self, filename):
        with open(filename, "r") as f_input:
            csv_input = csv.reader(f_input)
            self.details = list(csv_input)
    def get_col_row(self, col, row):
        return self.details[row][col]

chimed = adata('chime2.csv')

fermid = adata('fermi.csv')

while counter_chime < 600:
    frbcode = chimed.get_col_row(0, counter_chime)
    chime_cra = chimed.get_col_row(1, counter_chime)
    chime_cdec = chimed.get_col_row(2, counter_chime)
    chime_cra = float(chime_cra)
    chime_cdec = float(chime_cdec)
    sum = sum(chime_cra + chime_cdec)
    print (sum)
    counter_chime +=1
```

The error this returns is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\kaoet\Desktop\CODING\trial1.py", line 32, in <module>
    sum = sum(chime_cra + chime_cdec)
TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable
```

I am not sure what the problem is.

Comment: ‘sum’ is a built-in function. Don’t use that name for your own variable. Just use ‘s = chime_cra + chime_cdec‘

Comment: `chime_cra` and `chime_cdec` are floats, not sequences. If you want to add them, use `chime_cra + chime_cdec`. Your `sum(chime_cra + chime_cdec)` does not make sense.

Comment: By the way, nowhere does the error say "while loop is not iterable". That does not make sense.

Comment: as @Trevis answered it below. I would like to add this: Sum is a function that adds the given list or a iterable. It is usefull if you have a lot of numbers in a list and you want to add them up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As `chime_cra` and `chime_cdec` are `float`, you do not need to use `sum` to have their sum.
You could do `sum([chime_cra, chime_cdec])`, that is an iterable for `sum` and it would not complain at the first loop.

It is not necessary, though, you should just use `chime_cra + chime_cdec`.

Furthermore, that line of code would later lead to another error because you are re-defining `sum` when you use it as a variable name. Instead, you should find a meaningful name for your sum result.

Comment: When I use ``` print (chime_cra + chime_cdec)``` it simply just puts the two values of the numbers side by side.

Comment: That would be the case if they are strings, and won't happen if you keep the `float`calls.